# Displaying 5 Columns in one row on footer - Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi I am trying to display 5 responsive rows in one line in footer but it seems like its not working exactly the way I want it.

Here is my code

```
<footer>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="col-md-2 customer">
                <h3>Customer Service</h3>
                <p>Unit 36/65 Marigold St,Revesby
                NSW 2212 <br>
                P | (02) 9773 8773
                <br>
                F | (02) 977 8125
                <br>
                E | info@trevell.com.au</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 company">
                    <h3>The Company</h3>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Our Profile</li>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Home Designs</li>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Showcase</li>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Commercial</li>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Career</li>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Blog</li>
                      <li><a href=""></a>Terms & Conditions</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 dc">
                    <h3>Our Display Center</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=""></a>Freemans Ridge Estate</li>
                        <li><a href=""></a>Homeworld Camden South</li>
                        <li><a href=""></a>Brooks Beach Estate Horsley</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 lp">
                    <h3>House & Land Packages</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=""></a>House & Land Packages</li>
                        <li><a href=""></a>Display Home for Sale</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 nl">
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
        <p>Be the first to know about Trevelle Special offers</p>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </footer>
```

I even tried to replace `col-md-2` with `col-md-3` but the last columns moves to next line. Here is attached image I am trying to make exact like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XN6K.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this example

CSS:

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  div.col-sm-7.seven-three{width:60%!important;}
  div.col-sm-5.five-two{width:40%!important;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 seven-three">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#000;">Column 1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#333;">Column 2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#444;">Column 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#555;">Column 4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#666;">Column 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xuybnje/)

Comment: Brilliant man!. 

One thing more can I add small google map inside column1?

anyways thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 customer">
                <h3>Customer Service</h3>
                <p>Unit 36/65 Marigold St,Revesby
                NSW 2212 <br>
                P | (02) 9773 8773
                <br>
                F | (02) 977 8125
                <br>
                E | info@trevell.com.au</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 company">
                <h3>The Company</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Our Profile</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Home Designs</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Showcase</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Commercial</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Career</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Blog</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Terms & Conditions</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 dc">
                <h3>Our Display Center</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Freemans Ridge Estate</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Homeworld Camden South</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Brooks Beach Estate Horsley</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 lp">
                <h3>House & Land Packages</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""></a>House & Land Packages</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a>Display Home for Sale</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 nl">
                <h3>Newsletter</h3>
                <p>Be the first to know about Trevelle Special offers</p>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

you shouldn't use nesting `col` under a `row`, and keep all children of `row` plus to 12

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="comp-name">
                <h2>Company Name</h2><br>
                <p>Halimun Street 25
                Jakarta, Indonesia
                12850</p><br>

                <a href="#">YourDomin.com</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 menu-list">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Sitemap</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 lorem">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Neque</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Suspendisse</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Dictum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Porttitor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tincidunt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Enim lobortis</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Neque</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Suspendisse</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Dictum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Porttitor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tincidunt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Enim lobortis</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="assets/images/footer_logo.png" alt=""><br>
            <p class="text-muted">Copyright © <?php print date("Y"); ?> Freepik
            Company S.L. All rights reserved.</p><br>
            <p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```